# Is it a good idea to put a conversion operator in an iterator to convert it to pointer?

Tags: c++

I saw the following code today:

```
options.push_back(&*i);
```

Where `i` is an iterator and the container `options` stores pointers to the type of `*i`. The resulting `&*i` is a bit ugly and I started to wonder:

> Is it a good idea to add a conversion operator for converting to a pointer of `*i`?

What do you think?

Comment: I would avoid it; implicit conversions are often causes of headaches in overload resolution, plus, when the target is a pointer, they silently enable stuff that may be nonsensical for your object (like `if(i)`). `&*` is not so bad after all...

Comment: @matteo-italia:
I thought a lot about this and... I agree with you. It's a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

It's not ugly, but perhaps dangerous: If the source of iterator `i` was dynamically allocated and is deleted before container `options`, this would result in a container of invalid pointers.
If not, this is perfectly valid code. In order to make it more readable, you could add braces:

```
options.push_back(&(*i));
```

I wouldn't use a conversion operator here if you're not using this construct all over your code.